# Communicate with the stdin/stdout of a child process asynchronously

Tags: c, winapi, process, pipe, stdout

I want to create a child process, and read its stdout asynchronously. It turns out that I have to create a named pipe to connect to the stdout, since anonymous pipes do not support asynchronous reads.

I know about the functions `CreateProcess`, `CreateNamedPipe`, `CreateFile`, and `ReadFile`, but is there some sample code that connects them all? I am blinded by the sea of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that does this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365603(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically you add your pipe handle to the STARTUPINFO structure in the CreateProcess.

I think I used that code sample before : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That code sample uses anonymous pipes, which only works for synchronous reads, which block until the child process outputs something. I'd like to not multi-thread a simple file read.